# What is the purpose of Access URL Variables in AMP? Where and how are they used?

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

Can you please provide an explanation of Access URL Variables in AMP, their purpose and how and where they are used?

For example, can you please provide a step by step example of how you integrated them into an amp-story?

the official amp-access sample for demos of first-click-free and view counting

- https://rocky-sierra-1919.herokuapp.com/
- https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [amp-access documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access):

> When configuring the URLs for various endpoints, the Publisher can use
>   substitution variables. The full list of these variables are defined
>   in [the AMP Var
>   Spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md).
>   In addition, this spec adds a few access-specific variables such as
>   `READER_ID` and `AUTHDATA`.

Access URL variables allow you send vital information regarding the user or the session by including them in the URL. The best example would be `READER_ID`, which can be used to uniquely identify each user.

For eg. consider you have set up `authorization` endpoint in your `amp-access` configuration as follows :

`https://publisher.com/amp-access.json?rid=READER_ID&url=SOURCE_URL`

Then authorization call from your page will go with the variables `READER_ID` and `SOURCE_URL` substituted as follows:

`https://publisher.com/amp-access.json?rid=amp-s90UCBp2NixS3-wpVmKsSw&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Famp.html&__amp_source_origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000`

Now your backend server can identify users uniquely by checking the url parameter `rid` and get the source url from url parameter `url`. You can use all of the Access URL variables similarly. For more info refer [AMP-Access Docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access) and [AMP-Access Example](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-access/)

Comment: Hi Chris, do you maybe know if there is a way to add our own custom URL variables to the URL builder? We would need something like ?jwt={$jwtFromLocalStorage} in the URL.